# image is shown which is inputed in type file in run as server but not shown in browser

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, jsp

I want to input an image file, which I want to show in a specific `<div>` before uploading in my `jsp` page of a spring project. When I run the project on eclipse as **run as server**, It shows the image after I input the file. But in the browser, the image is not shown.

Here is my index.jsp:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 ownPic">
          <div class="row">
               <div id="imgContainer"></div>
                <br/>
              <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
               <input type="file" name="file" id="image"/><br><br>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my addEmployee.js:

```
 $("#image").on('change',prepareLoad);
 function prepareLoad(event)
    {
        files=event.target.files;
        readURL(this);
    }
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(150)
                    .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

[image: This is the run as a server on eclipse]

[image: This is the browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your browser's cache. Let me know if this solved the problem. :)